# Lebesgue Integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am in need of guidance for the following question: Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Show that $\mu(\{x:|f(x)|\geq n\})\leq 1/n\int |f|\mu(dx)$ for each $n>0$.

Comment: You need to show the work you've done in order to solve the problem, otherwise your questions will get downvoted and/or deleted.

Comment: I am fairly new to this site, do you mean provide my attempt on the question I am asking about?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for any $n$,

$$\int_X |f| d\mu \geq \int_{\{x: |f(x)|\geq n \}} |f| d\mu \geq \int_{\{x: |f(x)|\geq n \}} n \;d\mu = n \cdot \mu (\{x: |f(x)|\geq n \})$$

This is just Markov's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement